# How do you create a temporary queue using PHP stomp library?

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm using the **PHP Stomp Client** (version 1.0.0) to connect and send messages to **ActiveMQ** (version 5.7.0).

I have read that if you subscribe to a destination called `"/temp-queue/"`, this will trigger ActiveMQ to create a temporary queue.

However when I try this it creates a queue called `"queue://temp-queue"` instead of a temporary queue.

Is there any way to get Stomp to create a temporary queue on ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create the temp queue and only using the name `"/temp-queue/"` then that's the problem, the temp-queue portion is the destination prefix, you still need to give it a name like `"/temp-queue/1234"` or some such.  Usually the name value comes from a UUID or some other unique Id generator.

Comment: Great thanks. This works - I can see them in the logs briefly until they're gone...